# Very quiet sound on ALC887-VD

Tags: sound, alsa, 17.10, headphones

I've installed ubuntu today, and as I tried to watch something on Youtube/listen to music I can't even hear the sounds. (I use headphones, but the same is with the speakers).

Well, they ARE playing, but on 150% of loudness in Settings > Sounds it feels like ~%5.

Also sounds are a bit distorted.

Ubuntu v17.10
Intel ALC887-VD (Strangely, it's 'Realtek Generic' in alsamixer now).

I've tried to reinstall Alsa/Install pulseaudio (no effect).
Tried to increase all values in Alsamixer (still no effect).
Tried to google that problem and tried to fix it by other guys advices, but nothing helped me.

Someone had same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, you just need to set sound channel amount from 2ch to 6ch in `alsamixer`